# How to set Image Source as div/img background-image, using Javascript and not Jquery?

Tags: javascript, image, background-image, src

How to do this in JavaScript?

The height with percent is not working on chrome, and also this is not working on IE 5 emulation.

I was wondering if we can achieve the same result using JavaScript and also make height 100% work in chrome and IE 5 emulation?

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("img").each(function(i, elem) {
            var img = $(elem);
            var processing = $(this).attr("src");
            var div = $("<div />").css({
                "backgroundImage": "url(" + processing + ")",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
            });

            div.html(img.attr("alt"));
            div.addClass("replacedImage");

            img.replaceWith(div);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is something close to what I am looking for but how can we do the same with javascript?

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vkarpov15/NE9cu/)

```js
angular.
module('myApp', []).
directive('myBackgroundImage', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.css({
      'background-image': 'url(' + attrs.myBackgroundImage + ')',
      'background-size': 'cover',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
      'background-position': 'center center'
    });
  };
});
```

```css
div.wide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

div.tall {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div>
    <h2>Vanilla Image:</h2>
    <img src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110811172434/fallingskies/images/f/fd/Totoro_normal.gif" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>Fill 200x100</h2>
    <div class="wide" my-background-image="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110811172434/fallingskies/images/f/fd/Totoro_normal.gif"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Fill 100x200</h2>
    <div class="tall" my-background-image="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110811172434/fallingskies/images/f/fd/Totoro_normal.gif"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure css solution.

```css
div.wide {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background:  url("http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110811172434/fallingskies/images/f/fd/Totoro_normal.gif") center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.tall {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background: url("http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110811172434/fallingskies/images/f/fd/Totoro_normal.gif") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <h2>Vanilla Image:</h2>
        <img src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110811172434/fallingskies/images/f/fd/Totoro_normal.gif" />
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <h2>Fill 200x100</h2>
        <div class="wide"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Fill 100x200</h2>
        <div class="tall"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```